# Are all restrictions in XSD is available in in Avro?

Tags: json, avro, jsonschema

I am using Avro and I want to know if the restriction used in XSD can also be used in JSon Schema?

For e.g. 
In XSD we have restrictions like following:

1)

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer"> <xs:minInclusive value="0"/><xs:maxInclusive value="120"/>
```

2)

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string"><xs:pattern value="[a-z]"/></xs:restriction>
```

If I want to define an element with similar restrictions will I be able to do in Json schema?

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're asking here. What does Avro have to do with JSON Schema?

Answer (score 1):

For restricting numeric types, the *latest* JSON schema spec is here: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#range

For strings, the *latest* JSON schema spec is here: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html

You should check which version of JSON schema Avro is based on (so you should look up the Avro specification), and check whether it implements the full specification (sometimes restrictions are imposed).

Answer (score 1):

According to avro specification https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html,
you cannot impose a limit on field values, you only define the type of the field.

e.g. field can be int (32 bit signed integer) or long (64 bit signed integer) etc.

You cannot limit the values this field will have.

If you want to force limits on fields, it is the responsibility of your application reader/writer to validate the fields as needed.